# Typescript not infering non null members of an object

Tags: typescript, type-inference

Apologies if this question was already asked, I'll gladly close it if there is an answer for this.

Quite often I want to do field validation in my code, but typescript does not seem to figure out that I am doing just that.

Here is a simple example to illustrate my issue.

```
interface Something {
   a?: string;
   b?: string;
}

function validateFieldsExist(obj: Something) {
    return obj.a && obj.b;
}

function doStuff(obj: Something) {
    if (!validateFieldsExist(obj)) {
        return;
    }
    console.log(obj.a.length);   // TYPESCRIPT COMPLAINS
}
```

Is there any way I can achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare that function as a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) to tell the compiler that it checks its argument's type:

```
function validateFieldsExist(obj: Something): obj is Required<Something> {
    return !!obj.a && !!obj.b;
}
```

[Demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EwAtQDmyA3gFDIVwD8AXMgM5hSEDc5FARrQ066QL6lSMAK4gEYYOhDIAbnAA2wACZxIAMWAQFy+gFEAHsEYAKdBwBWdDNjyEAlHXMXkx5ACUIARxHAoEZQAeGxx8EAIAPhJ2Cn8wESgZAEIk5wA6OGQAMizkFPSONkFhMQkpGWV0VHiYGDNLayxQh2iKCmAYZBMk+SVVDS0dfSNTZ3t7VrapuISQNinBKYRpenQFCDSFdAJ6iwzNiHC8exZkAHoz5AA5dGRoKHQoJIFSIA)

Comment: Right, this looks good, that I don't have to reassign that value, the other question is - Required strips all ? modifiers. What if I wanted to check only obj.a ? Is there any way the compiler can infer a that without saying `obj is {a?: string, b: string}` ?

Comment: You can write that type explicitly in the type guard.